# Delete file when deleting row from table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

On my website I use simple file management. User can upload files, see the list and delete them. In database I have one table `Files` which contain information about files (**file name**, description, insert date).

I display all the files in `GridView` control with `SQLDataSource`.

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Files WHERE id = @id"
```

What I want to do is to delete the asocciated file when user deletes row from table. I was trying to do this in `OnDeleting` event but it seams that I have to execute another `SELECT` to get file name. Is it the only way to do this? Or is it any other better way? Or how to get the file name from inside the `OnDeleting` event?

**EDITED:** Databse is SQL Server, but it is not important in this case. I store files in file system. In database there are only names of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this from the GridView.RowDeleting event, you can use the passed-in parameter GridViewDeleteEventArgs to get the row about to be deleted.  Assuming the name is in this row, you can then use it to delete the file.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than deleting your row directly, create a stored procedure called something like deleteFile(@ID int).  Inside this proc, get the filename:

```
Select FileName From Files Where ID = @ID
```

Then Delete the file suing whatever method you're using to delete actual files.

Then delete the row

```
Delete Files Where ID = @ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I know they can be evil, but this  seems like a place where triggers could be used, that way if the delete query is run from multiple places the file would still be deleted.

if it is MS SQL

DECLARE @Command varchar(8000)
SELECT @Command = 'del c:\' + DocID FROM Deleted
xp_cmdshell @Command

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to cross reference the table entry with the file - presumably they both have a unique file name? If so, you could use that to delete the file from the same place in your code-behind that you are issuing the DB delete command.

Comment: I have filename in the table. But the question is how to get the file name from inside the OnDelete event? Should I call SELECT or is there any mechanism which allows getting all the affected rows (like table DELETED inside trigger in SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

Lukasz,

If you are using a Gridview to bind the data, you can define the DataKeyNames attribute and then in the RowDeleting event do the following:

```
string documentName = (string)GridName.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
DeleteDoc(documentName);
```